# Ruby on Rails - form.submit() Jquery not passing parameters as JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to auto submit a form when the page loads using the *jQuery* code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#finds_expense").submit();
});
```

The form submission requires the parameters as **JS**. When I submit the form manually, it works perfectly, but when I use jQuery's `(document).ready`, somehow the parameters are passed as **HTML**, not **JS**. I appreciate any help on this. Had been stucked with this problem for quite some time. TQ.

Below is the code for `finds_expense`:

```
<div id="month-lookup"> 
<%= form_tag search_expense_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: "finds_expense" do %>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-8">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= text_field_tag :month,  params[:month], 
                placeholder: "month", 
                autofocus: true,  
                class: "form-control search-box input-lg" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= text_field_tag :year, params[:year], 
                placeholder: "year", 
                autofocus: true,  
                class: "form-control search-box input-lg" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success", id: "submit_expense") do %>
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Send
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Try the second answer in the duplicate tag post. If it didn't work, i will reopen the question.

Comment: The solution did not work for me. I already try changing from .submit() to trigger('submit.rails'), but the parameters are still being passed as HTML, not JS. Appreciate to reopen the question. TQ

Comment: Ok, I reopened it :)

Comment: Do you have `remote: true` in your form ? `<%= form_tag XXXX, remote: true%>`

Comment: Can you share the `finds_expense` form code?

Comment: Did you tried with .trigger('submit') ?

Comment: Yes, I already used in remote: true in the form. Below is the code for [finds_expense]

Answer (score 0):

If you call the `.submit()` method in the form object the `remote: true` option won't work.

An option is to trigger the form using the `.trigger('submit')`.

Another solution might be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var formData = $("#finds_expense").serialize();
  $.ajax({
   url: '...',
   data: formData,
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'apploication/script'
  });
});
```

Comment: It works!. Thanks a lot @Rodrigo. I just changed the type from 'POST' to 'GET'. Many thanks!!